# Akka custom load balancing

Tags: load-balancing, akka, actor

I'm using Akka 2.10. I have a scheduler which sends a bunch of messages (crawl tasks) to worker routers (8 workers) every N seconds (e.g. 5 secs).

I want to somehow track the load on the worker actors (e.g. number of messages in mailbox of actors) and if they exceed some threshold, decrease the period of scheduler.

The question is what kind of actor statistic I can use? Are there any built-in metrics?

Comment: In case of local workers you can try to use bounded mailboxes for them. Otherwise you may find something useful in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19811456/2144307) answer.

Comment: Or in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19815597/2144307) answer.