# Simple Akka mailbox configuration to discard overflowing messages

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have a system with 2 actors, which share the same configuration. This desired configuration is: "the mailbox should have a max capacity of 1 message, and any overflowing message should be discarded".

What is the easiest way to set this up?

I have tried putting the following in (Play Framework's) `application.conf`:

```
akka.actor.default-mailbox {
    mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.BoundedMailbox"
    mailbox-capacity = 1
}
```

But it doesn't work: the actor's mailbox still piles up messages when busy, and processes each of them when available. Either the actor does not give a damn about the contents of `application.conf`, or the above config is incorrect.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Because this is not what they are made for, extended functionality comes at a price](http://letitcrash.com/post/17707262394/why-no-mailboxsize-in-akka-2), [ofcourse there is a workaround in sense of a redesigning your application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617580/scala-mailbox-size-limit)

Comment: Your question is quite similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19807316/2144307). Yo can find a couple of  possible solutions there.

Comment: Reading mailbox size is not possible in Akka2, isn't it? If I should redesign my Scala app, so be it. I've used Akka so far because I want to run periodic tasks, like "run this function every second, unless it's still running". How to do this in Scala?

Comment: If you need to run something every second, you should take a look at the scheduler build-in in Akka. Just call system.scheduler.schedule(initialDelay, interval, your-function). You can also use the scheduler to send messages to an actor once or using a set interval.

Comment: @pushy Thanks for your suggestion, it looks like what I need. The API indicates `def schedule (initialDelay: Duration, frequency: Duration)(f: ⇒ Unit)`, but I'm pretty inexperienced in Scala, so would need a code example of this call. The function would be a public function defined in an external `Object`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If like me you want a mailbox with a max capacity of 1, and discarding overflowing messages, I recommend using `java.util.Timer` instead of Akka.

This is what I wrote in my Scala program:

*MyTask.scala:*

```
object MyTask extends TimerTask {
  var isRunning = false;

  def run() {
    if (!isRunning) {
      isRunning = true

      [...]

      isRunning = false
    }
  }
}
```

Executing the task after 0ms, repeating every second:

```
new Timer().schedule(MyTask, 0, 1000)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to set the default mailbox for all actors in the actor system to a bounded mailbox with only one item, it's much better to configure your actors to use a specified mailbox as described in [the Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/mailboxes.html#Mailbox_configuration_examples) . Either through deployment or directly in code.

Your mailbox configuration also needs a push-timeout that you can set to 0 if you want to discard messages immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I kept the same code but added `mailbox-push-timeout-time = 0s` in `application.conf`, but it didn't change a thing.

Comment: Setting push-timeout to 0 worked in my case. Thanks!