# Scheduling a function to be run every second with Akka's Scheduler

Tags: scala, akka

I want to run this Scala function every second:

```
object AuthTasker {
  def cleanTokens() {
    [...]
  }
}
```

Akka's Scheduler has the following function: `schedule(initialDelay: FiniteDuration, interval: FiniteDuration)(f: ⇒ Unit)`

Can I use that function in order to call `AuthTasker.cleanToken()` every second?

Comment: What makes you doubt that you can?

Comment: @ghik I'm new to Scala, and haven't seen examples of how this `schedule` function is called. In understand best with examples.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer your question: Yes, you can call AuthTasker.cleanToken() every second with the schedule method. I recommend the following (included the imports for you):

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("system")
system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 1 seconds)(AuthTasker.cleanTokens)
```

Note: This updated code calls the scheduled method every one second rather than every 0 seconds. I caught the mistake when looking back at the code.

Comment: The code you're posted (using an actor) is very similar to what I have now. I have a problem with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816148/simple-akka-mailbox-configuration-to-discard-overflowing-messages

Comment: I've updated my answer after sleeping on it. Much of the code that I originally had was unnecessary. This code has been tested in the REPL and works.

Comment: Thanks, it replies to the question. Still stuck with my problem though (cf link in my comment above): even doing this way, it uses some sort of message queue behind the scenes.